# Datasnapshot not returning correct data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve data from Firebase, if the `user` hits "attend event" icon in the app which is an ImageView, then it should be saved to their profile.

I have been reading about `ValueEventListeners`, `ChildEventListeners` and I think my best bet is to use the `ValueEventListener` because I need a `datasnapshot` of the `postid` which the user has "saved" (attend). Also, have read about queries, it seems like that could help me and I am playing around with it to see how to incorporate it into my data, but so far no luck.

Below is a link to my JSON tree so you can see the structure of the data.

Is there a way to "skip" a child to read the next child because it contains the specific data you are trying to work with in *that* particular case / method, and return *that* data, or do you have to go in order always? Do I have to query that data to make it so the posts show up in the user's profile?

Posted an Image link of the database. Hopefully, someone can help.

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhFEU.png)

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
private void myAttendingEvent() {
        eventsImAttendingSecondButton = new ArrayList<>();

        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Event");

        Query query = reference.orderByChild(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        eventsImAttendingSecondButton.add(snapshot.getKey());
                    }

                readSaves();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readSaves() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList_attendingEvent.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                    for (String id : eventsImAttendingSecondButton) {
                        if (post.getPostid().equals(id)) {
                            postList_attendingEvent.add(post);
                        }
                    }
                }

                Collections.reverse(postList);
                eventsImagesAdapter_attendingEvent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Second Method** I have tried to retrieve the `postid`. In my mind this should work, but I'm not getting anything back. If user hits "attend" event ChildEventListener should read that datasnapshot and bring it up in user's profile...

```
private void myAttendingEvent() {
        eventsImAttendingSecondButton = new ArrayList<DataSnapshot>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Event").child(postid);

        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot.equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
                    eventsImAttendingSecondButton.add(dataSnapshot);
                }

                readSaves();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        readSaves();
    }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not sure how to do what you're asking me to do. You want me to just copy and paste the Parent and child of the data that I am asking about here under the code or something? Or you want me to get the whole JSON tree on here somehow?

Comment: You're saying that data gets deleted when you runs this code. Edit your question to show the (minimal relevant) data before and after running this code, so we can see what is being deleted.

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen nothing is getting deleted. A user hits the ```ImageView``` in ```HomeFragment``` (attend event) and that "post" should be saved on his ```ProfileFragment```. Think of how on Instagram we can *Save* posts. It's the same concept. My parent node is **Attending Event**, and child to that is **postid**, and child to that is **userid**. If the userid is true then it should appear on their profilefragment as a that user IS "attending" that event.

Comment: @AlexMamo trying to explain as best I can. Does it make sense what I am asking for? Think Instagram... similar concept.

Comment: It's not about adding more words, it's about adding the JSON that you're reading to your question as text. Without that it's impossible to understand what your code will do, and the image you shared is not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if anyone really needs this information, but after playing around with the ChildEventListener and ValueEventListener for two days I figured out that the one I needed was indeed the ValueEventListener finally have accomplished my goal. Hopefully it helps someone!

The way I did it was this:

```
private void myAttendingEvent() {
        eventsImAttendingSecondButton = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Event");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        eventsImAttendingSecondButton.add(snapshot.getKey());
                    }
                }

                readSaves();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```